# DAX: getting last row per ID based on index

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like the get the last row for every ID, based on the index column. So for every ID, the index has to be the highest possible (maximum) index for that specific ID.

I tried the following DAX-measure, but it does not give me the correct output. The expected output would be 127, yet the measure returns 5.

```
Last row of ID's = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[ID]),

    GROUPBY('Table', 'Table'[ID]),

    FILTER(Table, Table[Index] = MAX('Table'[Index])))
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I added some sample data in text format

| ID | Date | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10151 | 2021-10-04 | 1 |
| 10151 | 2021-10-05 | 2 |
| 10151 | 2021-10-06 | 3 |
| 10151 | 2021-10-07 | 4 |
| 10151 | 2021-10-08 | 5 |
| 10152 | 2021-10-04 | 6 |
| 10152 | 2021-10-05 | 7 |
| 10152 | 2021-10-06 | 8 |
| 10153 | 2021-10-04 | 9 |
| 10153 | 2021-10-05 | 10 |

Comment: Post your sample data in text format.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why doesn't simply `MAX('Table'[Index])` give you what you want?

Comment: @JosWoolley I want to use the last row of every ID to further filter some other columns. By choosing the last row, I'm sure that all values are at their most recent for each ID, which is necessary for the further calculations.

Comment: So how and where precisely do you want these values to be returned? As a single-column virtual table to be used in some further expression?

Comment: I would like a table that return 1 row for every ID, being the last row. I know filtering on max(Date) would be more sensible, but that's not possible for this particular problem. That way I could e.g. count the amount of ID's based on the given table. @JosWoolley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new table with the following:

```
=
VAR T1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        'Table',
        "Max Index",
            CALCULATE(
                MAX( 'Table'[Index] ),
                ALLEXCEPT(
                    'Table',
                    'Table'[ID]
                )
            )
    )
RETURN
    FILTER(
        T1,
        [Max Index] = 'Table'[Index]
    )
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. However, this deletes all other columns in  the original table, which I need for further calculations.

Comment: This doesn't delete anything in the original table. It creates a **new** table.

Comment: That's true. When creating the new table using your suggestion, it creates a new table with only 2 columns, being ID and Max Index. But e.g. the Date column is not present in the new table.